# Wahrheit versus Wahrhaftigkeit

Tags: word-usage, difference, usage

What is the difference between *Wahrheit* and *Wahrhaftigkeit*? Because I don't seem to get the difference if there is any.

How can one possibly use *wahr* and *wahrhaftig*?

Answer (score 6):

**Wahrheit** is the simple word **truth**. 
You can tell the truth or lie, it is just up to you.

**Wahrhaftigkeit** is the strong strive for truth: Someone who is **wahrhaftig** does NEVER want to tell a lie.

It is an attitude regarding telling the truth.

[This](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahrhaftigkeit) wikipedia article has quite good insights, but it is German.

> *Wahrhaftigkeit* ist eine Denkhaltung, die das Streben nach Wahrheit beinhaltet. *Wahrhaftigkeit* ist keine Eigenschaft von Aussagen, sondern bringt das Verhältnis eines Menschen zur Wahrheit oder Falschheit von Aussagen zum Ausdruck.Die Wahrhaftigkeit kann falsche Aussagen nur durch einen Irrtum hervorbringen. Zur Wahrhaftigkeit gehört die Bereitschaft für wahr Gehaltenes zu überprüfen.

Translation:

> *Wahrhaftigkeit* is a mindset containing the strive for truth.
>   *Wahrhaftigkeit* is not the property of any statement (true or false), but describes the relationship of an human being to telling the truth / lying.
>   Someone being *wahrhaftig* can only give false statements if he is wrong. 
>   It is important for someone being *wahrhaftig* to check statements for their truth before believing them.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy. The difference is the same as between *truth* and *truthfulness*:

> wahr --> true
>   wahrhaft --> truthful, truthfully
>   Wahrheit --> truth
>   Wahrhaftigkeit --> truthfulness, veracity